# How to compute year and month period between two xs:dates?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Older MarkLogic versions (pre XQuery 1.0-ml) seem to have supported a function to calculate a year and month period between two dates (https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:subtract-dateTimes-yielding-yearMonthDuration).  The documentation page now suggests that the "-" operator should be used with versions later than 0.9-ml.  That operator returns a period in days and hours, though, not in years, months and days and it is not possible to correctly convert from a days and hours periods to years and months due to leap years.  Is there another function that performs this operation for XQuery 1.0-ml?

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly easy to construct a yearMonthDuration yourself. I have done so in [ml-date-ranges](https://github.com/grtjn/ml-date-ranges/blob/master/date-ranges.xqy#L328). It comes down to:

```
let $year-diff := year-from-date($max) - year-from-date($min)
let $month-diff := month-from-date($max) - month-from-date($min)
return
  xs:yearMonthDuration("P" || (($year-diff * 12) + $month-diff) || "M")
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks!  Your ml-date-ranges library looks most useful!